# Add a new string array to a var of List string

Tags: linq

I need a compact way to create a var object and initialize with constant strings

When I use the following

```
 var types = new List<string> {"blah1, blah2, blah3" };
```

I get only one element in my list. How can I initialize the list with 3 elements.

Comment: So if you give it one string, you get one string. If you want three, how many do you think you should give it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to separate the elements by `,` char, try using the `Split` method, for sample:

```
var list = "blah1, blah2, blah3".Split(',') //break by ,
                                .Select(x => x.Trim()) // remove spaces
                                .ToList(); // convert to list
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks very much for the prompt response.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var types = new List<string> {"blah1, blah2, blah3" };
```

to

```
var types = new List<string> {"blah1", "blah2", "blah3" };
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks a lot for the quick answer!